# How to set environment variable for everyone under my linux system?

Tags: linux, unix, bash

Can I have certain settings that are universal for all my users?

Comment: Is it EXPORT? append that and it is global?

Comment: i think it is only append on current session , when you open new session in terminal it would be disappeared

Comment: Yes, export is only for current session, but I didn't have good results on adding my variable to `/etc/environment` file. That's weird the only environment variable I have there is `PATH` but its content is different from the `PATH` that I see when I list all the variables via `env`

Comment: I was missing to run `source /etc/environment`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

As well as `/etc/profile` which others have mentioned, some Linux systems now use a directory `/etc/profile.d/`; any `.sh` files in there will be sourced by `/etc/profile`. It's slightly neater to keep your custom environment stuff in these files than to just edit `/etc/profile`.

Comment: What if some users use another shell, like zsh?

Comment: this is not global ... it is restricted to the shell.. too bad it is the most accepted answer

Comment: zsh will source .sh files in /etc/profile.d/, you can see it from /etc/zshrc @Matthieu Napoli

Comment: Scripts are not used for ROOT user.

Comment: @Bily, this is not correct for all systems. For example on my Ubuntu 21.04 there is no /etc/zshrc and the global config at /etc/zsh/zshrc does not source stuff from /etc/profile.d/

Answer (score 122):

If your LinuxOS has this file:

```
/etc/environment
```

You can use it to permanently set environmental variables for all users.

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/04/linux-variables-de-entorno-permanentes.html

Comment: Works for me too on Kubuntu

Answer (score 41):

[man 8 pam_env](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env)

[man 5 pam_env.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_env.conf)

If all login services use [PAM](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/), and all login services have `session required pam_env.so` in their respective `/etc/pam.d/*` configuration files, then all login sessions will have some environment variables set as specified in `pam_env`'s configuration file.

On most modern Linux distributions, this is all there by default -- just add your desired global environment variables to `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`.

This works regardless of the user's shell, and works for graphical logins too (if xdm/kdm/gdm/entrance/… is set up like this).

Comment: +1 you also need to reboot after adding a variable in pam_env.conf cause instantly on the fly $ echo $variablename does not show

Comment: You don't need to reboot, you need to relog-in.
(No rebooting critical servers for me)

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to my distro, Mint 17.2. The preinstalled file is entirely commented out, and if I add something like `echo foo>/home/me/bar` and reboot (and log in again), that file doesn't get created. (There's probably a more elegant way to test this, but I wanted to be sure before commenting here.)

Answer (score 19):

Amazingly, Unix and Linux do not actually have a place to set global environment variables. The best you can do is arrange for any specific shell to have a site-specific initialization.

If you put it in `/etc/profile`, that will take care of things for most posix-compatible shell users. This is probably "good enough" for non-critical purposes.

But anyone with a `csh` or `tcsh` shell won't see it, and I don't believe `csh` has a global initialization file.

Comment: `/etc/environment` actually seems to set environment variables at for me, even as the root user. I know that `/etc/environment` is on amazon linux and ubuntu. I didn't get to check if works for csh, tcsh, or zsh.

Comment: it is not specific to the shell you are using, it is truly global

Answer (score 15):

Some interesting excerpts from the bash manpage:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the `--login` option, it
>   first reads and executes commands from
>   the file `/etc/profile`, if that file
>   exists. After reading that file, it
>   looks for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands
>   from the first one that exists and is
>   readable. The `--noprofile` option may
>   be used when the shell is started to
>   inhibit this behavior.
>   ...
>   When an
>   interactive shell that is not a login
>   shell is started, bash reads and
>   executes commands from
>   `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if
>   these files exist. This may be
>   inhibited by using the `--norc` option.
>   The `--rcfile` file option will force
>   bash to read and execute commands from
>   file instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and
>   `~/.bashrc`.

So have a look at `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`, these files are the right places for global settings. Put something like this in them to set up an environement variable:

```
export MY_VAR=xxx
```

Comment: Note that on classic Unix systems, both Bourne shell and Korn shell also read /etc/profile - it is probably the mostly widely used location for system environment setting. Some versions of the C shell look in /etc/csh.cshrc and /etc/csh.login as well as per-user locations; others do not use any system environment setting file.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for as far as setting the env for non-login shell users.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have accidentally downvoted this when for a while the arrows weren't visible... would you mind editing this (typo "environEment" in the second to last line, for example) so I can remove the downvote?

Answer (score 6):

Every process running under the Linux kernel receives its own, unique environment that it inherits from its parent. In this case, the parent will be either a shell itself (spawning a sub shell), or the 'login' program (on a typical system).

As each process' environment is protected, there is no way to 'inject' an environmental variable to every running process, so even if you modify the default shell .rc / profile, it won't go into effect until each process exits and reloads its start up settings.

Look in /etc/ to modify the default start up variables for any particular shell. Just realize that users can (and often do) change them in their individual settings.

Unix is designed to obey the user, within limits.

**NB**: Bash is not the ***only*** shell on your system. Pay careful attention to what the /bin/sh symbolic link actually points to. On many systems, this could actually be ***dash*** which is (by default, with no special invocation) POSIXLY correct. Therefore, you should take care to modify *both* defaults, or scripts that start with /bin/sh will not inherit your global defaults. Similarly, take care to avoid syntax that only ***bash*** understands when editing both, aka `avoiding bashisms`.

Answer (score 4):

Using PAM is execellent.

```
# modify the display PAM
$ cat /etc/security/pam_env.conf 
# BEFORE: $ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /var/tmp/myproject/click.py &
# AFTER : $ python $abc/click.py &
DISPLAY  DEFAULT=${REMOTEHOST}:0.0 OVERRIDE=${DISPLAY}
abc   DEFAULT=/var/tmp/myproject
```