# How to add a path to sys.path permanently

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys.path

Let's say I have a Python file which I would like to import and use anywhere else; how can I write a Python code to insert the path of this module to `sys.path` permanently?

Answer (score -1):

You could set your [PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/pythons-sys-path-value) environment variable. This could be done by setting it in the [/etc/profile file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) if you are on Linux.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using python code instead of cmd, and for windows

Comment: Rather than modifying the path, you could include your package in c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages (or the equivalent directory for your version of Python).  That's the purpose of that directory.

Comment: @Just4Help Windows does have environment variables as well. They can be set from within the control panel http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm