# Ubuntu global variable works only for root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hosting

I am added variable in `/etc/environment` , but after restarting variable sets only for root, other users need execute `source etc/environment` or they don't get any value:

```
user: echo $VAR
                 # blank
root: echo $VAR
value
```

(I know we can set up variables per user, but in my case I need global variable for all users.)

Answer (score 0):

try `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`

check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641494/1654077