# Where is the LANGUAGE environment variable set?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, locale, configuration-files, archlinux

I'm using **zsh** on my **archlinux**.
My **LANGUAGE** environment variable was set to **fr** but I wanted to set it back to **en_US.UTF-8** so I did it in my **~/.zshrc** file.

But was it the best place to set it? Isn't it dirty? This works but only for my user's zsh configuration.
Isn't there a more proper place to set it? Where?
Where is **LANGUAGE** usually set? I didn't find it in my system, I tried my **/etc/locale.conf** but I only found **LANG**, **LC_COLLATE** and **LC_TIME** in it.

Comment: I recommend looking through the short discussion on [How to set environment variable for everyone under my linux system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out where **LANGUAGE** is set :
It is set by **KDE**.

I just used the KDE settings tools.

But according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#The_LANGUAGE_priority_list), I shouldn't use en_US.UTF-8 as a value, but something like "**val1:val2:val3**" : so if I want to set it with my **.zshrc** file, I should use a value like "**en:fr**".

But kde handles that.