# How to set environment variables using Node?

Tags: node.js, bash, process, environment-variables

I am trying to automatically set three AWS environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_ID` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`) which are derived from the JSON returned by `aws sts assume-role`.

Normally if I wanted to automatically set environment variables I would write a Bash script, say `setvars.sh`:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=something
```

and then

`source setvars.sh`

I know that if you do `process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'something'` in a Node script, it won't affect the parent process.

Is there a workaround to be able to use a Node script (rather than Bash, which will be tricky to manipulate JSON with) to set environment variables this way?

Comment: wrt *rather than Bash, which will be tricky to manipulate JSON with*, it is not that tricky with `jq`, have you tried it?

Comment: I have previously used jq. I don't particularly like it - I don't use it frequently enough to remember the syntax between usages, and it becomes one more dependency to install just for this one small task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set environment variables using a bash script and *run in a shell*, they are accessible just to the processes which are run in the *same shell*. So you will need to run the Node app in the same shell to access those variables.

Now another approach is to add them in `process.env` object, so you can write a config script just to load all the config variables and require it at top of your Node app. You need to design the application in such a way that you can use all the configuration in same file.

For Example:

config.js:

```
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'something'
```

app.js:

```
// Starting point of your app
require('./config');
const app = require('express')();

// Use the config
// AWS_API(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY);

// Other App Logic
```

This approach is mostly used in development environment, in production you might want to use the first approach or you can add the configuration globally using `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`. Refer [how-to-set-global-environment-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system)

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is the answer. Instead of having a Bash script which calls a Node script to set the variables, the whole thing has to be driven by the Node script.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the JSON file and set your environment variables in process.env:

```
process.env['environment_variable_name'] = 'environment_variable_value';
```

**NB**: This will be available only for that particular node process and its children, not globally available.

Comment: Yes, I explicitly mentioned in my question that I know that this method will not work.

Comment: @SteveBennett What's different about this from the accepted answer? In that also it sets the process.env variable and uses it in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion to the accepted answer, 
You can also define your ENV in a file, and import a specific env config based on a release.

This way you can set ENV files for your staging, development or production environments in static configs if required.

**From dotenv repository/docs**

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

> Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add
>   environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE.
>   For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

> process.env now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file.

```
const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```

So for you, you may want to do an async call from AWS to get those ENV variables, or perhaps save them within a `.env` file

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv