# How to set the environment variables to be used by the service running on Linux machine

Tags: linux, bash, devops

The `my-service` that is running on the Linux machine needs to be supplied with the `ENV_VAR` environment variable. It works if I declare this variable in the `etc/environment` file with:

`vim /etc/environment`

then adding an extra line:

`ENV_VAR="My Value"`

And finally reloading it with:

`source /etc/environment`

I then can re-start the `my-service` with:

`sudo service my-service stop
sudo service my-service start`

I wonder if I could avoid declaring `ENV_VAR` variable in the `etc/environment` file. Is there a way to declare the environment variable to be seen by the `service` using any other approach?

Comment: Add `ENV_VAR="My Value"` to `my-service` or to a file which this service includes.

Comment: Please clarify. Or better yet, post it as an answer so we could up-vote it.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What distribution are you running? `sudo service my-service stop` suggest you are not using systemd. Which service manager (rc-init, systemd, sysvinit, upstart, etc.) are you using?

Comment: `Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04`. It does come with the `systemctl`. Instead of `sudo service my-service start` I can start it with `sudo systemctl start my-service`  Is there a way to set up the environment variable using a command line (without messing up with the `my-service.conf` file?

Comment: So ubuntu uses systemd since some time. So do not use `service`, use `systemctl`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to declare the environment variable to be seen by the service using any other approach?

If your system uses systemd to manage the service, from [systemd.exec documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) section "Environment" you can add to your service file:

```
Environment="ENV_VAR=My Value"
```

Comment: No, that would be wrong. The environment of the service shouldn't be dependent on the environment from where it was run. Just create a template service (`my_service@argument.service`) if you want to pass arguments to your service. Or I guess as a workaround you could create a drop-in systemd service file with customized configuration, I've seen scripts that do that.

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to add an *Environment Variable* you could do a number of things:

1. Edit `/etc/enviroment` (All Users)
2. Edit `/etc/profile` (All Users)
3. Edit `~/.bashrc` (Just You)

Editing any of the files above will ensure that any time you startup your machine, your environment will have access to those variables.

You could also edit `my-service` or a file that `my-service` includes (as suggested by [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus)). This means that if you have write access to the source code for the `my-service` program or a file that `my-service` includes (calls before it's own execution), you could add a line to that file.

You also don't even have to edit a file! Whenever you launch a terminal you can make live changes to the environment simply by entering the text you would have added to one of the files mentioned above as a command. This environment change will be just like the `~/.bashrc` change, in that it will only work for the current user. If you plan to `sudo <command>`, you will have to first `sudo su` to switch to the super-user user, and then change the environment.

Weather you are editing a file or entering a command, I suggest using the following line of code. The `export` command will ensure that environment variable is accessible by `my-service`.

`export ENV_VAR=value`

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But setting up the environment variable in the terminal with `export ENV_VAR=value` and then starting the service with `sudo service my-service start` doesn't make the `ENV_VAR` available to the service.

Comment: I should have mentioned the user account difference. When you do ```sudo <command>``` It completes the command as the super-user. You would have to switch to the super user account ```sudo su``` then ```export ENV_VAR=value``` and then ```service my-service start```. I will edit my solution to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

It also works without quotes for example if you want to set environment variables for an asp.net core app;

```
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5001
```

You can set multiple variables using spaces