# How do I stop .NET Telemetry to stop collecting data in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, telemetry

### When updating my ubuntu system I saw the following messages.
**Telemetry

The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous and doesn't include command-line arguments. The data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.
Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry**

How can I disable the telemetry from collecting data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using this. This should disable the telemetry data collection.

```
export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
```

Update:
I agree with XPhyro. One can add this to the ~/.bash_profile as well.

Comment: It could be added that this line should go into your `~/.bash_profile` or a similar file if you do not use bash or have changed its path.

Answer (score 8):

### on windows in CMD or powerShell

> ```
> set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1 
> //or true
> set DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=true
> ```

### On linux, export to your bash profile

```
//This will open the nano text editor with your bash profile file.
nano ~/.bash_profile
 the following line at the end of the file:

// then type this, Save the changes Ctrl+X -> Y, finally -> Enter.
export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1

// finally reload
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Ubuntu and want to disable Microsoft .NET telemetry permanently for all users then it can be done by adding `DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1` line to `/etc/environment` file.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

> A suitable file for environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole (rather than just a particular user) is /etc/environment.

Also please see answers on [Setting PATH variable in /etc/environment vs .profile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile) and [How to set environment variable for everyone under my linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) questions for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora [for reference, or people following search results; Ubuntu may be different] the dotnet `.rpm` installs a script at `etc/profile.d/dotnet-cli-tools-bin-path.sh` that initially contains only `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"`

That seems a very good place to add `DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1`